# Is it possible to implement a SharePoint 2013 Remote Event Receiver in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, event-receiver

We are working on a SharePoint provider hosted app which is built in Node.js
Is it possible to implement a "Remote Event Receiver" in our Node.js app?

Is there any documentation out there I can go through?

Thanks a lot for looking into this.

Answer (score 0):

A remote event receiver for a SharePoint app is just a URL that points to a web service [Create a Remote Event Receiver in Apps for SharePoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj220043.aspx) and Microsoft has repeatedly stated that provider hosted apps can be implemented in any language with the most common one mentioned being PHP.  Since it's possible to create a web service with Node.js -- see [How To Write A Simple Node.js/MongoDB Web Service for an iOS App](http://www.raywenderlich.com/61078/write-simple-node-jsmongodb-web-service-ios-app)-- it should be possible to implement a remote event receiver with Node.js